# Processing Batch Job

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background**

I have a script that either takes a text file that contains a list of `player_ids` or not. If the user provides a `player_id` list i ensure that all the ids are part of the tranche date they provided and then run the process job for all the player ids in the list.

If the user has not provided a list of players to run the jobs on we run the process job on all the players that are part of the tranche date.

**Code**

```
import argparse
from nba import release_checks, s3, shell
from typing import List
from nba.process_jobs_off_sqs import batch
from nba.process_jobs_off_sqs.exceptions import BatchTimeoutException


def _get_all_player_id(tranche_date: str) -> List[str]:
    return s3.download_str_key(
        s3.S3Path(
            "player-datasets",
            f"ENVIRONMENTS/staging/{tranche_date}/all_player_ids_in_delivery.txt",
        )
    ).splitlines()


def _is_player_id_list_valid(
    provided_player_id_list: List[str], all_player_id_list: List[str]
) -> bool:
    for player_id in provided_player_id_list:
        if player_id not in all_player_id_list:
            raise Exception(
                f"The following player id: {player_id} in the text file is not part of the tranche you provided."
            )
    return True


def _launch_process_job(list_of_player_ids: List[str]) -> None:
    jobs = [
        {"player_id": player_id, "job_id": player_id}
        for player_id in list_of_player_ids
    ]
    try:
        batch.launch_and_await_batch("automated_player_selection", jobs)
    except BatchTimeoutException:
        print(f"Jobs are known to fail due data missingness.")


def _run_mentality_check(nba_folder_name: List[str]) -> None:
    try:
        release_checks.mentality_check(
            nba_folder_name
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--nba-folder-name", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--tranche-date", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--list-of-player-id-file-path")
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    all_player_id_list = _get_all_player_id(args.tranche_date)
    if args.list_of_player_id_file_path:
        provided_player_id_list = shell.lines_from_file(
            args.list_of_player_id_file_path
        )
        if _is_player_id_list_valid(provided_player_id_list, all_player_id_list):
            _launch_process_job(provided_player_id_list)
    else:
        _launch_process_job(provided_player_id_list)
    _run_mentality_check(args.nba_folder_name)
```

I am mostly looking for a code review for better python usage as i am new to python. I gave a vague background as i am less concerned on getting code review on the actual algorithm but more so about my code and how to make it more pythonic and clean.

Answer (score 1):

### Validation

This function `_is_player_id_list_valid` is stuck between two useful concepts - validating and returning `bool`, and throwing-or-not. Don't attempt to do a half-measure of both. Given its current name, it would be less surprising to do

```
for player_id in provided_player_id_list:
    if player_id not in all_player_id_list:
        return False
return True
```

If you want to keep the exception, then

- Delete the return
- Change the return type to `None`
- Use a more specific type than `Exception`
- Rename the method to something like `check_player_id_list`.

For this method you should also get rid of the loop, cast the lists to `set`s, use set intersection, and then base your error message off of *all* of the missing elements instead of just the first.

### Late serialization

Validation should be done on `tranche_date`. The sanest way to do this is expect a date of a specific format (which you probably already do, though you haven't shown it); parse it into a real `datetime` (or perhaps `date`), and then re-serialize it in `_get_all_player_id`. Its representation should only be `str` at the extreme edges of your program - in your argument parsing, and in your S3 call. In the middle it should be a real date type.

### Error messages

```
except BatchTimeoutException:
    print(f"Jobs are known to fail due data missingness.")
```

is... a little strange. You could print this and it would still be valid even if there were no timeout. Instead perhaps consider

```
    print('Batch timed out. Data may be missing.')
```

Note that this does not need to be an f-string. Also, what data?